Google Cloud Run job configuration and its peak memory usage
In a Google Cloud Run job configured with 4GB of memory and 2 CPUs, consisting of 20 total tasks with a concurrency limit set to 10, what would be the peak memory usage?
Is the allocated memory per task 3GB (3GB per task * 10 concurrent tasks = 30GB)?
Or is the memory shared across all the tasks, resulting in 3GB shared for all 10 tasks together?
Considering that the tasks are memory-intensive, with each task averaging 3GB of utilization, would the maximum/total memory usage at peak be 30GB (3GB x 10) or 3GB for all 10 tasks combined, thus 3GB at peak?
P.S: Not for Cloud Run (service), checking for Cloud Run Job

Each instance would bill you for 3 GB.
Each Cloud Run Job consists of one or more tasks. Each task runs one container.
The memory usage would be the total number of jobs * the number of tasks per job * 3 GB executed at the same time. You would be billed by the nearest 100 milliseconds per container task. For billing, it does not matter if the jobs run at the same time or independently as you are billed by CPU and Memory seconds.
Note: concurrency (parallel tasks) does not affect how much memory you are billed for, just how many tasks can run at the same time.

Is it same for cloud run job as well (Not Cloud Run)?
